# Increasing UX maturity of an organization

Tags: best-practice, process

I was asked by my boss to implement the UX practice in our organization and our UX maturity is like 2/10. It is a 70 years old financial organization with lot of departments and many of them got their own UX departments and designers. It will be a challenge to bring everyone on board under one UX hub (there may also be resistance from other departments).
Q: Once I assess the UX maturity in our organization, what should I do next in order to make sure that I am moving the UX maturity from lets say 2 to 3?
And what process shall I follow and what the timeline may look like?

Comment: Hi @Sam Brady, welcome to the site! This question is very interesting, yet quite broad, and therefore at risk to be closed. Can you boil it down to some more concrete questions? Would love to read what fellow UXers experienced in their careers.

Comment: Sure. I will try to ask specific questions.

Comment: Questions:
1. Once I assess the UX maturity in our organization, what should I do next in order to make sure that I am moving the UX maturity from lets say 2 to 3.

Comment: Vitaly's linked article is an overview article, linking to more detailed articles for each level. There you will find steps to progress to the next level.

Answer (score 3):

The question is quite broad, but I think that [The 6 Levels of Maturity](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ux-maturity-model/) by NNG should be a great starting point. It outlines the basic levels of maturity, discusses the challenges common to each level, and provides further materials dedicated to each one.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest steps to "level up" are:

- Define the UX strategy approach for the teams/products/projects: tactical or strategical.
- Introduce the basics of the Design Ops...and work on them
- Introduce the basics of the Research Ops...and work on them
- Define the skill matrix for the UX designers in your team.

**UX strategy:**

- Tactical UX involvement:  UI focused
- Strategic UX involvement: full process involvement

Can be used simultaneously in the company as some projects fit the tactical, some the strategical.

Tactical UX areas:

- Up – Secure your leaders’ help to get resources/support for the team.
- Across – Liaise with project managers and others as needs be.
- Down – Take on administrative responsibility in regard to Human Resources concerns, training, performance assessment, geographic concerns of having an international team, etc.

Tactics:

- How
- Small scale
- Short term
- Doing

Strategy

- Why
- Large scale
- Long term
- Planning

**Design Ops**

6 topics:

1. Mission
2. Principles
3. Values
4. Workflows
5. People governance
6. Tools & Infrastructure

3 Phases:

1. Preparation
2. Planning
3. Execution

5 principles

1. Organize (Team composition, role definition)
2. Collaborate (Rituals & meetings, Environment, Value)
3. Flow (Eliminate distraction, Get insights)
4. Standardize (Guides, Processes, Toolset)
5. Prioritize (Allocation, Estimation, Team-capacity, Uncovering bottlenecks)

**Skill matrix**

The basis of the skill matrix should be the needs of the company. For example, if there is no possibility to do a lot of research, you simply do not have to focus on these skills. So do not copy the UX skill matrix from another company, like IBM. It fits them, and not your company.